# Torchvision resize not recognising second dimension of pytorch tensor input

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I have a pytorch tensor of shape [512,512] and want to resize it to [256,256] I tried using

```
resized  =  T.Resize(size=(256,256))(img)
```

But I got this error

> Input and output must have the same number of spatial dimensions, but got input with spatial dimensions of [512] and output size of [256, 256]. Please provide input tensor in (N, C, d1, d2, ...,dK) format and output size in (o1, o2, ...,oK) format.

But the shape of img is not [512].

I also tried to play with the dimensions of the original image,

```
img = img[:100,:200]
```

and the error transforms into

> Input and output must have the same number of spatial dimensions, but got input with spatial dimensions of **[200]** and output size of [256, 256]. Please provide input tensor in (N, C, d1, d2, ...,dK) format and output size in (o1, o2, ...,oK) format.

so it only reads the second dimension, or like only the first line from the 2d tensor img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torchvision transforms expect the tensor to have a colour channel dimension (1 for monochrome or 3 for RGB for example) and optionally batch dimension. In other words, you'll need a shape of at least `(1, 512, 512)` rather than `(512, 512)`. The easiest way to add a dimension is likely using `unsqueeze()`:

```
resized  =  T.Resize(size=(256,256))(img.unsqueeze(0))
```